# How to get Union type from an array of objects in Flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype, flow-typed

For instance, imagine having the following list of items:

```
const items = [
   {
       key: "amalgama"
   },
   {
       key: "torin"
   },
   {
       key: "mascarpone"
   }
]
```

**What Flow type `ItemsKeyTuple` definition should be to get the following check?**

```
type ItemsKeyUnion = ...some stuff with items...

// so I would get the same to the following:
// type ItemsKeyUnion = “amalgama” | “torin” | “mascarpone”;

let a: ItemsKeyTuple;

a = "amalgama" // OK;

a = "tomatoes" // ERROR;
```

The main idea is to get instant check and help when using inside if-else, switch statements, taking into account a possibility to change keys in some moment in future and be sure that I would be noticed with `Flow` about places I need to adjust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work, you would have to infer the tuple's `key` values as literal string types. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be possible in Flow (unlike TypeScript), see [facebook/flow#2639](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2639). One of the workarounds would be to use an object type, utilizing the `$Keys` utility:

```
const dict = {
    "amalgama": {},
    "torin": {},
    "mascarpone": {},
};

type ItemsKeyTuple = $Keys<typeof dict>;

const items = Object.keys(dict).map((key) => ({ key }));
```

Then, you can use `Object.keys` to convert the dict into the original `items` array at runtime. Notice that I have subtly used `{}` as a value for the keys in `dict`. This is because if you have more properties other than `key`, you can put them in this empty object:

```
const dict = {
    "amalgama": { foo: 42 },
    "torin": { bar: true },
    "mascarpone": { baz: "hello" },
};

type ItemsKeyTuple = $Keys<typeof dict>;

const items = Object.keys(dict).map((key) => ({ key, ...dict[key] }));
```

[Playground](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAJgS2LAvDA3gKBjmAiAQwFsCAbAc2ILwC4MBfAGm1zyhACcExaHnd8JCMAIcADuACmvdE0z0A3JkxQAnmMkwAklElEIAaUmqAKgFcxpTWgAkR1RAA8ajSABm8JFAB8SzKEhYBF19GDQAeQAjACtJZAA6AGtjCAAKRGQASniSMVTU5NVMsO8YVPQYQph6TMy-K1gCOh09Q2NzS0k-AjD8KgoqPBgAemGYcINu3rYQEnZJCCHRmABRACU18LWFIA)